# How can I write this Drupal snippet more efficiently?

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-6, performance

I'm working on a patch to submit to the [Registration Code module](https://drupal.org/project/regcode) for Drupal. In short, is there a more efficient way to write the code below?

```
if (module_exists('regcode_voucher')) {
  $cnfg = variable_get('regcode_voucher_display', array('regform' => 'regform'));
  if (empty($cnfg['regform'])) {
    return;
  }
}
```

It seems like I should be able to reduce it to one `if` statement with `&&` combining two conditions, but I haven't found the syntax or the necessary php array function that would allow me to do that.

In case some context helps, the regcode_voucher sub-module allows users to enter their registration code on the user edit page. On our sites, after a "beta" period, we want to simplify the registration form by removing the registration code field; but we'd like users to still be able to enter the code on their account edit page. The code above is part of a patch that allows the regcode's hook_user changes to be bypassed.

Comment: I agree that there is no need to optimize this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code looks like good, what efficient do you want? Little changes may be:

```
if (module_exists('regcode_voucher')) {
  $cnfg = variable_get('regcode_voucher_display', null);
  if ($cnfg) {
    // do your actions
  }
}
```

And I don't recommend to merge if..., code should be clear and simpler to understand. If you merge these for optimizing, you win "tiny" milliseconds for real-live processors, but lost your clean code.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you returning an array from variable_get if the variable is not found? variable_get will always return a string or a serialized array (that needs to be unserialized). If I'm missing something, you can use array_key_exists('regcode', variable_get(...)) to check for the array key.

This should work... note returning "false" from variable_get as a default if the variable is not found, which will cause the if conditions to not match. I personally find this more readable than nested if statements (for 3+ conditions I'd nest, though).

```
if( module_exists('regcode_voucher') && variable_get('regcode_voucher_display', false) ) {
  // stuff
}
```

Comment: The array contained in the regcode_voucher_display contains a variety of settings (represented by a series of checkboxes on the admin form). Some of those check boxes represent options that have no bearing on whether to bypass the hook_user implementation. Only the 'regform' option should determine whether to run the hook_user changes.